# Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS Fails on Emulator Nexus 9 API 24

Tags: android

I want to navigate user to developer options to enable mock locations, like below

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));
```

But it's throwing ActivityNotFoundException

```
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS }
```

What's wrong with this code ?